# Android emulator don't works with ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED intent?

Tags: android, permissions, android-emulator

Does android emulator work with BOOT_COMPLETED intent and has BOOT_COMPLETED permission?
I got "Unknown permission android.permissions.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" warning in logs.

1. manifest.xml

`<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>`

1. W/PackageManager(   63): Unknown permission android.permissions.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED in package com...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a typo.  It should be `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` - no "s" on permission.